# Transformer: Which parameters are learned during training process?

Tags: transformer-model

I got some questions when tried to read and learn the Transformer paper "Attention is all you need":

1. Which parameters exactly are Tranformer model learned during training process since the attention weight matrix is temporarily calculated from "softmax(QK<sup>T</sup>/√d<sub>k</sub>)"? The only trained parameters i know are the linear transformation factor applied on input before entering Multi-head Attention and factors inside FFN. Is there any parameter else? I wish to have a clear and unambiguous summary please.
2. What is the role of FFN in this model? How does it process the data and why we need it? I wish to have a simple and direct explanation please.

Please forgive my grammar mistakes since English is not my native language. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

1. the parameters are the weights of linear layers refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73834605/nlp-transformer-learning-weights/74109211#74109211)
2. take a look into this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/485910/what-is-the-role-of-feed-forward-layer-in-transformer-neural-network-architectur)